# Insert value into table with stored procedures

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, and I'm now trying to learn how to use stored procedures. I need to make a stored procedure that can add a person into a table. The values the table contains are Name, Lastname, Age and sex.

An example of how it could be done?

Comment: which sql are you using? SqlServer/MySQL or others?

Comment: I would have said look it up...

Comment: First link when I search for "MSSQL INSERT PROCEDURE" ... http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2519/insert-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Since the SQL vendor is not specified:

```
-- SQL SERVER

CREATE PROC InsertValues(
@Name nvarchar(50),
@LastName nvarchar(50),
@Age int
@Sex bit
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (@Name, @LastName, @Age, @Sex)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures vary from one DBMS to another (unlike SQL which is pretty much universal). If you are referring to Oracle's PL/SQL it goes something like:

```
create or replace procedure MY_PROC is
begin
  insert into PERSON(NAME,LASTNAME,AGE,SEX) values ('Bruce', 'Wayne', 30,'M');
end MY_PROC;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL u can create a procedure via phpMyAdmin like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPerson(IN Name VARCHAR(50), IN Last_Name VARCHAR(50), IN Age   INT(3), IN Sex INT(1))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PERSONS (Name, Last_Name, Age, Sex) values (Name, Last_Name, Age, Sex);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can use that procedure by:

```
CALL InsertPerson('Ralph', 'Wiggum', 8, 1);
```

If you have made something wrong in your procedure, you can drop it by:

```
drop procedure InsertPerson;
```